# How to loop through inventory hostgroups and execute task for specific group?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Experts,

I am new to Ansible and learning to write playbooks. Stumbled upon an exercise and need some help-
loop through inventory host groups and and replace any existing content in /home/student/text1 with text depending on hostgroup: 
- if host is in A host group, text should be : welcome to group A
- if host is in B host group, text should be : welcome to group B
- if host is in C host group, text should be : welcome to group C

I could traverse through inventory via loop: "{{groups['all']}}" but how do I put another condition that if host is in A group do that and host is in other group B do this, and looping through entire inventory?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"replace any existing content in /home/student/text1 with text depending on hostgroup: - if host is in A host group, text should be : welcome to group A - if host is in B host group, text should be : welcome to group B - if host is in C host group, text should be : welcome to group C"*

A: I expect that if host is member of more groups, for example, B and C, the file /home/student/text1 should look like

```
welcome to group B
welcome to group C
```

It is possible to use the special variable [group_names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html).

> group_names: List of groups the current host is part of

For example

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: text1.j2
        dest: /home/student/text1

$ cat text1.j2
{% for group in group_names %}
welcome to group {{ group }}
{% endfor %}
```

(not tested)